# Grounding standard for mechanical/crimping connector

Tags: connector, grounding, standard

Can anyone tell me if there is a grounding standard that takes about mechanical/crimping connectors, I am looking for an IEC standard.

I cam across IEC 61238-1 but this talks about power cables, are there other standards specially dedicated for grounding purpose or can IEC 61238-1 be used?

Comment: what is the purpose of your grounding?

Comment: it's on power station grounding.